# SES error missing final '@domain'

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto, amazon-ses

I'm using python lib `boto` for sending emails via SES. And when I tried to send to more than 30 (but less than 50, so limit is not exceeded) recipients, I got an error:

```
  <Error>
    <Type>Sender</Type>
    <Code>InvalidParameterValue</Code>
    <Message>Missing final '@domain'</Message>
  </Error>
```

My `to_addresses` is empty list, all recipients are in `bcc_addresses` list.

What does it mean? Every recipient's address is valid and sender address is verified and valid.

Comment: how about 10 mails? any difference if compare with 30?

Comment: Do you have the setFrom set with a valid and authorized email address?

Comment: Make sure you check *all* email parameters that get included in the SES/SMTP call - in my case all From, To, CC etc were correct but I had a Reply-To (inserted by some custom logic) which wasn't a valid email - literally "missing final @domain"

Answer (score 6):

I had this error and the problem was that my `to_addresses` email address was malformed.

Comment: My "Return-Path' address was malformed (same issue).

Comment: Resolved my issue, I included 'no-reply@domain-name' or 'admin@domain' instead of solely using the domain name.

Answer (score 1):

I used a malformed e-mail address in `Source` when I got this error.

Answer (score 0):

Recently there might to be an issue with putting an email address at the end of a sentence that ends with a period the content of a message (in text/English) like:

"Send your request to user@domain.com."

SNS or some of message processors (on AWS) now appear to process textural content for words that look like domains. The sentence above passes grammar checks however seems to fails a regex for valid domain the period at the end suggests the could be follow on characters.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If you run into this issue, I ended needing to update Source and used something like this no-reply@YOUR_DOMAIN_NAME.com

```
    import { SESClient, SendEmailCommand } from '@aws-sdk/client-ses';
    
      const command = new SendEmailCommand({
        Destination: {
          ToAddresses: ['SOME_EMAIL@test.com'],
        },
        Message: {
          Body: {
            Text: { Data: "Test" },
          },
    
          Subject: { Data: 'Subject name' },
        },
        Source: 'no-reply@YOUR_DOMAIN_NAME.com',
      });

await SES_CLEINT.send(command);
```